# What's the best way to get all index values of a string in a string

Tags: c#, string

I want to get the index value of a string in its parent string but `big_string.IndexOf("small_string")` only returns the index of the first string it found.
For example:

```
string big_string   = "sabcdaskdeweusdahsabchdjuasdabc";
string small_string = "abc";
int position;

position = big_string.IndexOf(small_string);

// Output: => 1;
```

There are 2 other `abc` in `big_string` that `IndexOf` can't return the value.
I can only get the value if I create a new `big_string` and eliminate its first `abc`, add the position in to a list then loop until there are no `abc` left.

I think this is not the best way to get all index value of a substring in a string. In case I don't want to use the loop and substring. How can I do this?

Is there anyone here know a better way to achieve the purpose?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641326/finding-all-positions-of-a-substring-in-a-large-string-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression. The match object will contain all captures and each capture has index
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a Regular Expression-

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
        string big_string = "sabcdaskdeweusdahsabchdjuasdabc";
        string small_string = "abc";

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(big_string, small_string))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Index);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting solution:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> FindIndexes(string text, string query)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, text.Length - query.Length)
        .Where(i => query.Equals(text.Substring(i, query.Length));
}
```

From here: [C# - Finding All Indices of a Substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596639/c-sharp-finding-all-indices-of-a-substring)

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way will always be a loop but you don't need to substring :

```
var myString = "myteststring";
var search = "s";
var indexes = new List<int>();
var index = myString.IndexOf(search, 0);

while (index != -1)
{
    indexes.Add(index);
    index = myString.IndexOf(search, index + 1);
}
```